# Modelsim .WLF file version error

Tags: simulation, hdl, modelsim

I am using Modelsim ALTERA STARTER EDITION 10.1d and am importing a waveform file but am getting the following error.

**The WLF file version is 132.Modelsim 10.1d can read up to and including WLF file version 121.**

I have tried importing the same file into Modelsim 13.1 and am still receiving similar problems. If anybody knows what version of Modelsim I need to open this file version your help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version number is the fourth byte in the WLF header (121 = 0x79). I manually edited a version 121 file to bump up this field and got the same version warning you are seeing. Your version 132 file should have 0x84 in its fourth byte. You could manually edit the file to reduce its version and hope the format is otherwise compatible with the older version of Modelsim but there are no guarantees.